# SWTBot - Wait for MessageBox

Tags: java, shell, swt, messagebox, swtbot

I am currently writing SWTBot tests and I encountered the problem that at one point I need to wait until an operation is finished and an Info-MessageBox informs me about the completion.

This is how I currently try to do it:

```
   public void generateCode() {
      SWTBotTree projectExplorerTree = bot.viewByTitle("Project Explorer").bot().tree();
      projectExplorerTree.getTreeItem(name).contextMenu("Generate Code").click();

      bot.waitUntil(Conditions.shellIsActive("Info"), 20000);
      bot.button(IDialogConstants.OK_LABEL).click();
   }
```

This is the message box I am waiting for:

[image]

But I get the following exception as SWTBot fails to recognize the message box:

```
org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.widgets.TimeoutException: Timeout after: 20000 ms.: The shell 'Info' did not activate
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.SWTBotFactory.waitUntil(SWTBotFactory.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.SWTBotFactory.waitUntil(SWTBotFactory.java:386)
```

Anyone with a solution for my problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, for some reason the message box was created by native code and that's why SWTBot couldn't find it!

Comment: So what did you do about it?

Comment: I don't know the exact solution - I am just tester and developing the software itself is not my business. I told a dev that I have this problem and that I suspect the message box to be a native widget. He built a workaround which causes a dummy SWT message box displayed instead when running the SWTBot test on it. I don't exactly how to do that but that is a workable solution.